# JavaScript: Changing default functions using subclass?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, subclass

I'm trying to make a simple game using JavaScript. I want each level in the game to have slightly different behaviour. However, I also want some default behaviour since not every part of the game will be changed.

I thought I should try to use subclassing and inheritance, maybe using a level base like this:

```js
"use strict";

function LevelBase() {
 this.load = function(level) {
  if (level === 1) {
   new Level1(this); // Can't do this = new Level1(this);
  }
 };
 this.func = function() {
  return 123;
 };
}

function Level1(game) {
 this.prototype = game;
 this.func = function() {
  return 456;
 };
}

var game = new LevelBase();
game.load(1);
console.log(game.func()); // Should print 456
```

However, this doesn't work. It still uses the default behaviour, and I have a feeling is is an awful method that will make everything overly complicated. Is there a working method to do something like this?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an approach that will work in IE11 or any other ES5 enviroment.

It relies on a couple of utility functions to define your classes, it supports single inheritance and overloading. You could keep the functions in a smaller script that is loaded first or keep it at the top of your file.

What mostly informed my approach is that I like any solutions I use to have clean looking code and this is what I came up with prior to 'proper' classes in JS.

```js
/*
 This function attaches a prototype object
 to a constructor function and returns it
 
 It also adds a super & base properties
 which can be used to infer which class an object came from (It's constructor function)
 
 e.g. var obj = new Class();
 
 Or using base on a class to check what it inherits from.
 
 Class.base = Base or Null if it has none
 
 obj.super = class;
*/
function _class(c,p) {
 p.base = null;
 p.super = c;
 c.prototype = p;
 
 return c;
}

/*
 This function takes a base class, constructor function and prototype object
 
 First the properties of the base prototype are iterated through,
 and any that aren't already on our new prototype are copied
 
 This essentially allows us to overload behaviour on the prototype by
 redefining it in decendants.
 
 Next a new constructor function is created that calls the base constructor first
 and then the derrived constructor afterward.
 
 function.apply() is a javascript function that can be applied to function objects
 in essense it's saying "Call this function as if you were a member of the first argument
 (the 'this' variable which would be the new object when the constructor is used) and
 use the same arguments that this outer function was called with".
 
 Another way to explain this is
 
 var obj = new nc(10);
  -> calls into nc with one argument '10'.
   -> That then calls into the base constructor with the same argument and 'this' set to the new object
   -> That then calls into the derrived constructor with the same argument and 'this' set to the new object
*/
_class.extends = function(b,c,p) {
 for (var pr in b.prototype) {
  if (!p[pr]) {
   p[pr] = b.prototype[pr];
  }
 }
 
 function nc() {
  b.apply(this,arguments);
  c.apply(this,arguments);
 }
 
 p.base = b;
 p.super = nc;
 nc.prototype = p;
 
 return nc;
}


var BaseClass = _class(
 // Base Constructor
 function(v1,v2) {
  this.v1 = v1;
  this.v2 = v2;
 },
 
 // Base prototype (Use for constants or class functions)
 {
  printValues: function() {
   console.log(
    this.v1,
    this.v2
   );
  }
 }
);

var DerrivedClass1 = _class.extends(BaseClass,
 function(v1,v2) {
  
 },
 
 {
  // It isn't defined here but this prototype contains the functions from the parent
 }
);

var DerrivedClass2 = _class.extends(BaseClass,
 function(v1,v2) {
  
 },
 
 {
  // This overloads inherited behaviour
  printValues: function() {
   console.log(
    "V1: " + this.v1,
    "V2: " + this.v2
   );
  }
 }
);

var obj_1 = new DerrivedClass1(10,20);
var obj_2 = new DerrivedClass2(30,40);

// This uses inherited behaviour
obj_1.printValues();

// This uses overloaded behaviour
obj_2.printValues();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can directly overload with `game.func = ...`.

```js
"use strict";

function LevelBase() {
 this.load = function(level) {
  if (level === 1) {
   new Level1(this);
  }
 };
 this.func = function() {
  return 123;
 };
}

function Level1(game) {
 game.func = function() {
  return 456;
 };
}

var game = new LevelBase();
game.load(1);
console.log(game.func()); // Should print 456
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was originally doing, but the problem with this approach is I don't know how to reset all the changes when switching to another level. For example, if I changed game.func along with a bunch of other functions, how could I change them all back to the default when loading another level? The new level may not necessarily change everything, so I want to keep the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

[If you don't have to support IE 11](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class) or are willing to transpile, `class` is a convenient way to implement inheritance in a way similar to how class-based languages do it:

```
class LevelBase {
  load() {
    // ...
  }

  func() {
    return 123;
  }
}

class Level1 extends LevelBase {
  func() {
    return 456;
  }
}

const level = new Level1();
console.log(level.func()); // Prints 456
```

IMO, this is the cleanest way to do inheritance, and it should perform well because it translates to prototype-based inheritance that is natural to JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for this. I would love to use classes but I'm really looking for a way to do this without transpiling if possible. It doesn't have to use objects, I just need some way to default to another function.